# How do I align a gradient to a line?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient

I would like to know how I can make the gradient tool aligned perpendicular to a line in photoshop, or how to set the exact angle of the gradient? I know that by pressing the Shift key, I can constrain the angle of the gradient tool to increments of 45 degrees, but let's say for example in the following photo, I want to create a layer mask to mask out the sky and the water, but I want the bottom part of the layer mask to be a gradient from the horizon to the water. How can I align the gradient exactly to the horizon line?

[image]

Comment: Rotate the image slightly so the horizon is level, then there will be no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Quick selection of the sky**, some images with hard contrast allow to make a quick selection from a channel.

In this case, from the **Channel window** > duplicating the **Blue Channel** > Menu **Image** > **Adjustments** > **Levels** > eliminate midtones moving shadows and lights to the center.

[image: levels]

A square frame at the bottom filled with black cover the sea.
Selecting the sky with the **Magic Wand** > **Invert selection** > Fill it with black.

For fine retouching with the **Brush Tool**, visualize the RGB channel clicking on the eye icon or/and change the new channel opacity

[image: retouch]

This is the *SKY/SEA* Channel.

Activate the RGB channel > with the **Shape tool**, choose **Line**, 6px weight, and make a line shape layer across the horizon from side to side of the file (green on the image):

[image: line]

From the **Layers Window** > Hide the background layer.

With the **Magic Wand** click on the bottom area below the green line to select the sea and keep the selection.

With the **Shape Selector Tool** > Select the line > **Copy** > **Paste** > **Transform** > **Rotate 90º**

[image: rotate]

**Channel Window** > Activate the *SKY/SEA* Channel clicking on the name > Make the RGB channel visible clicking on the eye to see the vertical line

[image: channels]

Choose the **Gradient Tool** > From Black to Transparent, make a gradient line from the bottom to the horizon following the vertical green line.

[image: line 1]

To make the other version, duplicate the SKY/SEA channel and using the same selection > Menu **Image** > **Adjustments** > **Invert**

[image: copy]

**Layers Window** > Duplicate the background image

Menu **Select** > **Load Selection...** > Choose *SKY/SEA* or *SKY/SEA COPY* and apply the mask:

[image: dupli]

Result:

[image: end]

Comment: I originally meant option B, but I would be interested in knowing how to do both if there is a big difference between the two methods